# 403 Forbidden Error when accessing file - httpd 2.4.23

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, http-status-code-403

I've installed HTTPD and PHP7 on my Fedora 24 64 bits. When i use the default path for 'DocumentRoot' ('/var/www/html') in the '/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf' file everything works perfectly but when I change the path to '/home/beto/web' it stops working.

When I try to access to 'localhost' the 'Fedora Test Page' with the non-default path works but if I try to access to any file, 'localhost/info.php' or 'localhost/foo.html' for example, it says:

> 403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access /info.php on this server.

I've checked the permissions with this 'namei -m /home/beto/web/info.php and this is the output:

> dr-xr-xr-x /
>
> drwxr-xr-x home
>
> drwxr-xr-x beto
>
> drwxr-xr-x web
>
> -rw-rw-r-- info.php

I've been trying for a while :'(

Comment: Always the client info regarding the error, is relatively useless, what does the Apache error log say? There lies the key to resolve your issue, Is it because of configuration or does it complains about OS permissions issue? Please paste the error and you will probably get the solution.

Comment: @ezra-s Thanks a lot :D, the problem was AH00035 because SELinux was blocking to the server the access to my folder